# "Color nonograms" or "Colored nonograms"

Tags: word-choice

Could you say, please, which phrase is better,

> color nonograms

or

> colored nonograms

Comment: Got no idea what a nonogram is, but "color nonograms" = nonograms of (specific) colors, while ''colored nonograms" = nonograms which are of different colors or are not black-and-white at least. 

P.S. Googled it, Wiki says: These puzzles are often black and white, describing a binary image, but they can also be **colored.**

Comment: Some context and examples are needed. Both are valid as is.

Comment: I found a website introducting [nonogram](http://www.nonograms.org/), they used "colour nonograms".